# Dropdown menu disappears when i hover

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

I have a problem with my menu. I have a dropdownmenu but when I hover its shows it for a second but then it disappears. See it on https://www.klokhof.be.

How can I fix this? WordPress website.

See pictures here.

https://klokhof.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Schermafbeelding-2021-02-22-om-10.52.38.png

https://klokhof.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Schermafbeelding-2021-02-22-om-10.46.57.png

Comment: Please add a snippet of the menu. But most likely your dropdown disappears because menu item and dropdown itself should be wrapped in single component which tracks hover.

Comment: How do you mean? My apologies for my brief wordpress knowledge.

Comment: As already stated, post your code here. This has nothing to do with wordpress, rather normal HTML and CSS (maybe JS)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/103mmu9 The deal is that element which toggles dropdown is separate from dropdown. The dropdown is opened whule you are hovering over the link, and disappears when you hover over something else. You should find the way either to add `data-toggle="dropdown"` to `li` element instead of `a`, or place dropdown inside `a` (bad option but will work at least)

Answer (score 0):

**Straight Solution and fixes**

Your CSS is not following proper structure, lets have some fixes.

1.
you have to remove all border from here ".bka_menu" class
https://prnt.sc/103mljp

```
.bka_menu{
   border:none; 
    //Remove all or add border:none
}
```

2. Add two CSS properties in ".navbar-default" class
   https://prnt.sc/103mpbl

**`display: flex;`**

**`align-items: center;`**

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    border-color: transparent!important;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex; // Add this
    align-items: center; // Add this
}
```

3. add "margin-left:auto" to navbar-collapse (for the align right side of the nav)
   https://prnt.sc/103mr3h

```
.navbar-collapse{
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

4. Add padding top the ".navbar-right a" class
   https://prnt.sc/103mt5r

**`padding-bottom: 10px;`**

**`padding-top: 10px;`**

```
.navbar-right a {
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 15px!important;
    padding-right: 15px!important;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;  // Add this
    padding-top: 10px; // Add this
}
```

[image: Final Output with clean fix]